# Determinate if a rectangle fits into another

Tags: android

I'm using canvas to draw two rectangles one inside another (it's an interactive image crop view)

[image]

The trouble is that the blue rectangle can be also scaled and rotated (I'm using Matrix() on a bitmap to do this):

[image]

I can calculate the bounds without the rotation like this:

```
if( ( centerX - offsetX ) > ( greenRectangleWidth / 2f ) )
     // out of bounds
```

But I'm completely lost how to calculate if the blue rectangle is still inside the green rectangle if the blue rectangle is rotated.. I think I could potentially solve this in two ways:

```
1. Read the pixel color of the edges of the blue square, if any of the edges will be outside the green square, the color will change. This seems like an unreliable way and I don't think I can even read 'pixel value' from canvas, then I would need to convert it to bitmap on each frame which will be very slow.

2. Calculate if any of the corners of the blue rectangle cross the edge of the green rectangle, but I'm not sure where to go from here.
```

Any hints please how this could be solved most efficiently? Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to draw with canvas? drawable is other option to achieve this square

Comment: @Niceumang unfortunately yes, because it's an interactive "image crop" view

Answer (score 0):

If both a blue and green rectangles are stored as `Rect` I would expect the line

```java
if (!rectGreen.contains(rectBlue)){
  // blue is not inside the green
}
```

To work for both conditions - rotated and not rotated (I've not tested it)

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains(android.graphics.Rect)